# different desktop wallpaper on local and remote desktop on same pc but different networks

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

One production PC is a bit badly set up:

The PC is on one domain/network, connected to another domain/network (target).
Because of this, when logging on locally, all the programs are quite slow.

Solution: Log on locally, use remote desktop on the same pc, but the remote connection automatically connects onto the other domain where the programs are fast(er). (usernames are the same)

Do not ask me why the company did this, there can be nothing changed about this, and I hope I got the explanation right - not sure.

======

question: I would like to set a wallpaper (allowed by policy) onto the local pc. Then I want to remote desktop onto the same pc, but there should be a different wallpaper (set wallpaper disallowed by policy).

Unfortunately, setting a wallpaper (simply color red) on the local account also changes it on the remote desktop account - usernames are the same.

I already set the remote desktop connection to "no wallpaper" but the different color is always there.

I want to achieve:
On the local machine there should be a wallpaper in red (for not using because slow) and on the same machine with remote desktop another wallpaper color (green for usage because other domain/network).

How can I do this?

====

For questions please ask, I do not know if I got this correctly... :(

Comment: Have you tried removing it from the domain, deleting the user folders in `c:\users`, then re-adding it to the domain?

Comment: It is a PC from the company, I am not supposed to do anything with its domain settings, just wanted to know if there is another way to visualize the local account and the "proper" account via RD.

Comment: In that case get your IT department to perform the maintenance for you.